# Жадная загрузка документов в doctrine mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine2, doctrine-mongodb-odm

Кажется что-то упускаю в работе доктрины с монго. Подскажите пожалуйста:
Есть

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\MappedSuperclass
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorField("type")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({
 *   "hotel"="App\Document\Attributes\HotelAttributes",
 *   "apartment"="App\Document\Attributes\ApartmentAttributes",
*/
abstract class AbstractAttribute 
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex()
     */
    protected string $id;
    ...
}
```

И несколько классов наследников, типа:

```
namespace App\Document\Attributes;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="attributes")
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @MongoDB\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class HotelAttributes extends AbstractAttribute
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(
     *     type="int",
     *     nullable=false,
     *     name="bed_places",
     * )
     */
    protected int $bedPlaces;
```

И

```
class Resources
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(
     *     targetDocument=AbstractAttribute::class,
     *     storeAs="dbRefWithDb",
     *     orphanRemoval=true,
     *     cascade={"all"}
     * )
     */
    protected AbstractAttribute $attributes;
    ...
}
```

Ресурс создаётся нормально, но при выборке по id, поле attributes не подгружается, пока не обратишься к свойству напрямую, т.е.:

```
$resource = $this->dm->getRepository(Resources::class)->find($id);
$resource->getAttributes() - возвратит
```

[image: dump в twig]
а `$resource->getAttributes()->getCreated()` - дату создания и все поля.
Вопроса два:

1. Как заставить доктрину автоматом подгружать все данные?
2. Как указать репозиторий для абстрактного класса в моём примере?

Спасибо за помощь.